# Trying to configure 2 swimlanes in Jira to be similar

Tags: planning, kanban, jira

So I have 2 swimlanes in Jira on a Kanban board and I wanted to know if they can mirror each other? Or what might be the best way to go about this. I made one swimlane that I want only to have items that are on hold because we are waiting on more info. So I would ideally like to be able to move from one swimlane to another and no matter what status columns it would be under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you could base the swim lanes on queries. And use either a label or the flagged field to decide if something should be in the On Hold swimlane or not.